# Model is not bound on HTTP Postback

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a list of articles. Allow a user to edit them one at a time and post it back to the database. I can display what is there ok but when the form posts the model is not bound to the http postback. My code is below.

I have the following POCO input class:

```
public class ArticleInputModel
{
    public int articleID { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

The following controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Set(ArticleInputModel articleInputModel)
    {
        // Do Work
    }
```

And the following view:

```
@model List<TRN.DAL.Article>

<div class="container">
    @for (var articleIndex = 0; articleIndex < Model.Count; articleIndex++)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "Articles", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <h1 id="title" class="editable mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;">@Model[articleIndex].title</h1>
            <div id="content" class="editable mce-content-body" style="width: 100%; position: relative;" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
                @Model[articleIndex].content
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-trn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Are you returning that model from your Set controller method?

Comment: No it is being returned from a separate controller and posted to one with a completely different name.

It makes it to the controller the model is just completely empty.

Comment: It looks like your model is of type List<TRN.DAL.Article>, but your controller method takes a ArticleInputModel, can you try making the controller take in a type of TRN.DAL.Article and see if that works?  Although, the property names are the same, so I am not sure that would make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not rendering any inputs so there is no values to post back. You need to include hidden inputs for your properties you want to post back and use javascript to update the contents of the hidden input with contents to the editable elements (or use AJAX to post the values).

For example (note you are generating duplicate ID's in you loop so I have used a class name instead)

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Set", "Articles", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.Hidden("title", Model[articleIndex].title, new { id = "title" + articleIndex })
  @Html.Hidden("content", Model[articleIndex].content, new { id = "content" + articleIndex })
  <h1 class="title editable mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;">@Model[articleIndex].title</h1>
  <div class="content editable mce-content-body" style="width: 100%; position: relative;" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">@Model[articleIndex].content</div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-trn">Submit</button>
  </div>
}
```

Script

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  // Get values of contenteditable elements
  var title = $(this).children('.title').text();
  var content = $(this).children('.content').text();
  // Update hidden inputs
  var inputs = $(this).children('input[type="hidden"]');
  inputs.eq(0).val(title);
  inputs.eq(1).val(content);
});
```

Comment: Very nearly there. It is posting data (Thank you!) but it if i run in debug I can see it is setting title to "{ id = title1 }" and content to "{ id = content1 }"

Obviously without the quotation marks and the number is set to the index of the array.

Comment: Ignore me the script is not firing it is just returning the original value of the hidden field or "new { id = "title" + articleIndex }".

Comment: @DavidBainbridge, Sorry, I used the wrong overload of `@Html.Hidden` - see updated answer

Comment: Really basic error JQuery was not loading properly. Your script is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why submit each individually rather that all at once?

Comment: The page presents a list of all articles on the site. You then have the option to edit any one of them and update it. Some will not need updating.

It is designed for someone to moderate articles so they will look at all articles in the queue and may only choose to edit one or two.

It is a UI decision really. The alternative is paging through the articles one at a time.